# TypeError: Cannot read property 'searchField' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, typeerror

[image]

[image]

I am learning react-redux by following "The Complete Web Developer in 2020 Zero to Mastery" course from Udemy by Andrei Neagoie.And i have been following the changes made by the instructor in the code and doing the same things.And now i am facing this error & dont know to how to resolve this.I am new to redux part.I have attached two pics , first one shows error occurring in the browser and the second pic is the code in App.js.Also the editor is sublimetext so it is not highlighting some keywords.Thank you.

Comment: check if your state has `undefined`  or `null` value for `searchRobots`

Comment: Please provide code as text, not as screenshot

Comment: check for undefined like this in your mapstate to props searchField: state.searchRobots && state.searchRobots.searchField

Comment: @PeterLehnhardt  "https://github.com/bdamor5/react-redux-practice" App.js , reducer.js , action.js , constants.js , index.js are the relevant files and using these i am implementing the redux part.

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier & Sarthak Aggarwal . searchRobots has an empty string as the initial state.And when the user inputs something , searchRobots get updated with that inputed text.Did that answer your query?

Comment: yet my answer remains the same. check for undefined before you try to access the searchField property

Comment: @Sujit.Warrier i resolved the issue.When i recompiled the code there was a warning saying " the rootReducer is declared but never used" , so i though of removing the extra space where the rootReducer is residing and when i saved the file , the error was resolved.I dont know whether to be happy or not because this little detail had me scratching my head for hours.Is there a way to know about these little details in the editor? or are there any alternative editors which point out these typos?